# Forge MDK 1.15.2 crashes when executing runClient.launch

Tags: java, crash, minecraft-forge

i'm using Forge MDK 1.15.2, and Eclipse as IDE for modding. I currently have Java 8, and when i try to run the file runClient.launch, i just see an initialization window (just like a forge starting screen you know), but then it crashes. I tried to reinstall Java, to clear the build cache...

Here's the crash report :

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Who set us up the TNT?

Time: 14/05/20 12:42
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.rewind()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
    at net.minecraft.client.MainWindow.loadIcon(MainWindow.java:188) ~[forge-1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.MainWindow.setWindowIcon(MainWindow.java:152) ~[forge-1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:380) ~[forge-1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:accesstransformer:B,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:141) ~[forge-1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {re:classloading,pl:runtimedistcleaner:A}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251] {}
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_251] {}
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_251] {}
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_251] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.java:55) ~[forge-1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:81) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:65) [modlauncher-5.0.0-milestone.4.jar:?] {}
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:102) [forge-1.15.2-31.1.0_mapped_snapshot_20190719-1.14.3-recomp.jar:?] {}


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.MainWindow.loadIcon(MainWindow.java:188)
    at net.minecraft.client.MainWindow.setWindowIcon(MainWindow.java:152)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.<init>(Minecraft.java:380)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.lambda$launchService$0(FMLUserdevClientLaunchProvider.java:55)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.launch(LaunchServiceHandlerDecorator.java:37)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:54)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler.launch(LaunchServiceHandler.java:72)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:81)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:65)
    at net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:102)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.15.2
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.15.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_251, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 1013149720 bytes (966 MB) / 3235381248 bytes (3085 MB) up to 7618953216 bytes (7266 MB)
    CPUs: 8
    JVM Flags: 1 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump
    Launched Version: MOD_DEV
    Backend library: LWJGL version 3.2.2 build 10
    Backend API: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 4.6.0 NVIDIA 445.87, NVIDIA Corporation
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Hope you can help me !

Comment: tl;dr of dupe: you compiled with a newer version of Java than you're trying to run with.

Comment: yes ! i found some Java JDK 12 in my java folder, i removed it and reinstalled the whole thing. I also cleared my .gradle/caches folder, and it worked !